# mounting gps72h garmin

Tags: usb, usb-installation, gps

I cannot see my *Garmin 72h* on open CPN.
I have it connected to an USB port.

I run `lsblk`:

```
    NAME         MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
    mmcblk0rpmb  179:24   0    4M  0 disk 
    mmcblk0boot0 179:8    0    4M  1 disk 
    mmcblk0boot1 179:16   0    4M  1 disk 
    mmcblk0      179:0    0 29,1G  0 disk 
    ├─mmcblk0p1  179:1    0 27,2G  0 part /
    ├─mmcblk0p2  179:2    0    1K  0 part 
    └─mmcblk0p5  179:5    0  1,9G  0 part [SWAP]

    ~$ df
    Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
    udev              944220        0    944220   0% /dev
    tmpfs             193084     6044    187040   4% /run
    /dev/mmcblk0p1  27978924 15904344  10630280  60% /
    tmpfs             965416    36696    928720   4% /dev/shm
    tmpfs               5120        4      5116   1% /run/lock
    tmpfs             965416        0    965416   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
    tmpfs             193084       16    193068   1% /run/user/1000

    ~$ sudo lsusb
    Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:07e6 Intel Corp. 
    Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f2:b469 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
    Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0489:e078 Foxconn / Hon Hai 
    Bus 002 Device 002: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
    Bus 002 Device 013: ID 091e:0003 Garmin International GPS (various models)
    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The *Garmin* does appear on

```
Bus 002 Device 013.
```

Still, when I go to *System Information* and check the USB Devices, the *Garmin* does not appear and in `OpenCpn/options/connections/serials/Data` port I cannot see the *Garmin* USB or select anything.

And `Opencpn` doesn't read the *Garmin* (which has been successfully mounted with no hassle on a windows computer...).

Any suggestions are highly appreciated and the advisers highly blessed. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the output that appears in `dmesg -w` when you plug in the device?

Comment: i cannot post the output.... it's too long.... can i send it to you somehow? thanks

Comment: my mistake; I meant only the new output when you plug it in. It should start with something like `new high-speed device on bus 002`